# UnityScript, print in constructor + non-var variable doesn't work

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

When I try to create an instance of Monster class the print function doesn't seem to do anything. Why is that? I'm working with unity 4 if that's of any help. Also I cannot make a Monster class instance without using var, despite it being optional(allegedly).

```
function Update () {
    var mon = Monster("Torreadore");
    mon2 = Monster("blueberry");                //unknown identifier : 'mon2'
                                                //even though it's been said that var is optional in the js tutorial
}

class Monster
{
    var name : String;
    function Monster(n : String)
    {
        name = n;
        print(name + " has been created.");
    }
}
```

Comment: In Javascript, you cannot declare class in this way. Try to do Object way.

Comment: Yeah this is incorrect. But where are you trying to print too?

Comment: It's tagged with Unity, so I assume this is Unity javascript, which isn't true javascript... It's it's own thing. I am pretty sure that this is syntactically valid _Unity_ Javascript.

Comment: - Jay I'm trying to print it to the unity console. @Alex Wayne -Assets/testScript.js(14,9): BCE0005: Unknown identifier: 'mon2'. This error pops up in unity console(line 14 refers to mon2). Also could you write a little bit more how much the real js differs from the one used in unity? -kidz What do you mean object way? I haven't had any experience with javascript before(only with java), so sorry if the questions seem stupid.

Comment: [Read this](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=UnityScript_versus_JavaScript) There are some gigantic differences.  It's really a different language where some syntax is similar to javascript. If I were you I'd use the C# flavor variant. It's going to be less confusing.